# Barchart showing numbers instead of categories on y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have little familiarity with python and I would really appreciate your help on a matter.

I would like the barchart I'm trying to plot to show the column `Venue Category` on the Y-axis and `Weighted ratings` on the X axis. While I have been able to do the latter, I am unsure how to add venues categories on the chart.

Here is my code:

```
# Sorting by Rating
sort_rate = standardized_1.sort_values("Weighted rating", ascending=True)

# Creating bar chart
sort_rate["Weighted rating"][-10:].plot(kind='barh', color="Darkblue", alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 5), xticks=np.arange(0, 30, 2))

plt.xlabel("Weighted rating", labelpad=16)
plt.ylabel("Venue Category", labelpad=16)
plt.title("Top 10 Categories by Weighted rating", y=1.02, fontsize=18)
```

Here is the barchart:
[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
sort_rate[-10:].plot(kind='barh', x='Venue', y='Weighted rating', color="Darkblue", alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 5), xticks=np.arange(0, 30, 2))
```

You need whole dataframe rather than just ratings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much!! :)